# .NET How to increase allowed GET request URL length for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I am receiving callback from bank, but it only works with one request which has 1960 characters in get request.

The other longer request with more parameters is 2236 characters long, which doesn't reach our MVC action.

I already tried changing maxUrlLength to 4000(4000 characters?) in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="4000" />
```

But still first response doesn't reach MVC action.

They reported from their side for longer request:

> ERROR Problem with connection to the following URL

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using IIS 6 and above, also add following entry. This setting will be used if you have managed app pool rather than classic.

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="40960" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxUrl="40960" maxQueryString="2097151" />
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i dont have an access to iis, since i am using azure

Comment: You just need to add above entry into web.config. That should work.

Comment: I added still doesn't receive longer than 2056. do i have to do anytrhing else?

Comment: I hope you did not remove `httpRuntime` entry. You need both entries to make it work. See the updated answer.