# How to convert base64 to file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, upload

How do I convert a base64 variable to a sendable file in javascript? I need to call a file upload API with the converted file as a parameter to the API.

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64

Comment: You can use this function to create file http://stackoverflow.com/a/31592969/5138198